# How to clear android textedit field

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am traing to clear textedit field when it is focused. I know about hint option, but I wanna clear textedit everytime when user actives it, also if is filled by user (now user have to clear field manualy everytime he wants change value). 
I load fragments in my app so there are a lot of edittext fields which I wanna clear on focus, so is there universal method to do this, or I have to do it to all fields severally?
Should I create another java file to this method or put inside onCreate?

Comment: That seems very user-hostile. Under your plan, if the user types something into a field, moves to another widget, realizes that they need to fix something in the original field, and goes back to edit it... you wipe out what they typed in originally.

Comment: Don't do it this way. Provide a reset button instead that clears all fields if the user desires so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should you OnFocusChangeListener as is shown in code below:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    ((EditText)v).setText("");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: And should I put it in onCreate method?

Comment: now every time when your EditText lost focus and get it back , the edit text will be clear

Comment: Yes, that is my goal.

Comment: You can extends from EditText and set on FocusChange listener in your EditText and everywhere use its

Comment: Do you understand idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an [`onClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and set the textfield to an empty string when clicked. You need to add the listener for each textfield but you can reuse the same listener because the functionality is the same. You can set the listener on `onCreate`, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set an `View.OnFocusChangeListener` with the method `setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener l)`.

In the callback `onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)` you can do the following:

```
if (hasFocus && v instanceof EditText) {
  ((EditText) v).setText("");
}
```

Comment: you don't have to check instance of if you use OnFocusChangeListener only for EditText

Comment: OnFocusChangeListener can be used with any view. It is not good practice to rely on view being an EditText as this may break your code once. It works with your solution because you use the an inline class. However, as he has more views it would be better to have one class that implements the interface and set this for all the EditTexts

Comment: No, Konrad is right. You set the listener to the views you desire. No need to check for EditText. It will only break if you set this listener to a non-EditText view, which wouldn't make any sense. Yours is the bad practice, because in this case it wouldn't work and you wouldn't know why. It's better to get an exception so you know you've done it wrong.

Comment: You should know where you use OnFocusChangeListener if you set one for different type views you have to check instance of , but if you set it only for one type of view this checking is redundant

Comment: As I said with the inline class it works. However, as he has more views I would not do that, but implement this interface in another class and pass this class as the listener.